# Correct response for PROPFIND on a resource that does not exist

Tags: webdav

How should a WebDAV server response when it receives a PROPFIND request for a resource that does not exist?

The RFC seems to say you should always return a 207 and then use 404 for properties that don't exist.  But what if the resource itself doesn't exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right answer is 404, which is true in general for most methods.

Where does it suggest it should be 207?

Comment: That makes sense, but it never really says that anywhere in the RFC.  It only talks about returning the 207.

Comment: Well, it also never says that you'll get 401 when credentials are missing :-) All of HTTP/1.1 applies as well, always.